# How to add "h" list's items(elements)?

Tags: python, list, format, addition, items

I want to add "**h**" (meaning hours) to list's items/elements? Couldn't find nice and easy way to do it.

```
paivat = int(input("xxxxxxxx: "))
tyo = list()

# Codes...

tyo.append(tunnit)

print("Syötit seuraavat tunnit:", *tyo, "yhteensä", total, "tuntia.", sep = " ")
```

gives:

```
Syötit seuraavat tunnit: 5.0 4.0 yhteensä 9.0 tuntia.
```

I would like print it like:

```
Syötit seuraavat tunnit: 5.0**h** 4.0**h** yhteensä 9.0 tuntia.
```

Could you assist me with this?

Comment: This works fine. Thanx M Z 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way with f string literals:

```py
print(f"Syötit seuraavat tunnit: { ' '.join(map(lambda t: f'{str(t)}**h**', tyo)) } yhteensä { total } tuntia.")
```